# How to copy folder and subfolder using PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4, file-copying

Does anyone have an idea about copying folder and sub folders using PyQt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
from shutil import copytree
copytree(original_directory_path, copy_directory_path)
```

For more information, check the docs on `shutil.copytree` here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: What do you think of the new answer, @GeorgeBrighton?